# How to download a zipped folder and read a specific table from within that folder in R?

Tags: r, download

I am trying to read a specific table "ces_minor" from the folder located at https://dol.ny.gov/statistics-ceszip (warning: it's a direct download link)

The method I tried:

```
temp<-tempfile()
download.file("https://dol.ny.gov/statistics-ceszip",temp)
table<-read.table(unz(temp,"ces_earnings.txt"))
unlink(temp)
```

This resulted in the error on line 3:

> In open.connection(file, "rt") :
> cannot locate file 'ces_earnings.txt' in zip file 'C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2DSR6U\file33f440b0166'

Manually unzipping the tempfile using 7zip yielded an error as well, indicating that download.file is not downloading the folder correctly?

> 1 'C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2DSR6U\file33f440b0166'
> Headers Error
> Unconfirmed start of archive
> Warnings:
> There are some data after the end of the payload data
> 2 Data error: ces_earnings.txt

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. It works for me (if I change `read.table` to `read.csv` since it appears to be a CSV file). What OS are you using? What verison of R are you using? What does `file.info(temp)$size` return?

Comment: On Windows, adding `mode = "wb"` to `download.file()` might help

Comment: Windows 10, R version 4.1.2, file.info(temp)$size returns 919631 

mode="wb" was the solution, thanks!